# Dates after 19 January 2038 and strotime

Tags: php

This is my code:-

```
        foreach ($this->data['age'] as $row) {
            $nepali_date = strtotime($row['mem_birth_date']);
            $english_date = strtotime("-56 years -8 months -16 days", $nepali_date);
            $date = date("Y/m/d", $english_date);
            $now = date($now);              

            $age = ($now - $date);
            if ($age >= "18" && $age <= "24") {
                $i++;
            }
            if ($age >= "25" && $age <= "29") {
                $j++;
            }
            if ($age >= "30" && $age <= "39") {
                $k++;
            }
            if ($age >= "40" && $age <= "49") {
                $l++;
            }
            if ($age >= "50" && $age <= "59") {
                $m++;
            }
            var_dump($row['mem_birth_date']);
            var_dump($nepali_date);
            var_dump($now);
            var_dump($date);
            var_dump($age);
        }
```

When the $row['mem_birth_date'] is greater than 2037 year $nepali_date results boolean false. Can u tell me the problem and solution to.

Comment: most likely this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is any upper limit which is defined for the length of the string in the function. If the string is not in the correct format then the strotime will return false.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):-

> **Note:**
>
> **The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC.** (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer.) Additionally, not all platforms support negative timestamps,
>   therefore your date range may be limited to no earlier than the Unix
>   epoch. This means that e.g. dates prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work
>   on Windows, some Linux distributions, and a few other operating
>   systems. PHP 5.1.0 and newer versions overcome this limitation though.
>
> For 64-bit versions of PHP, the valid range of a timestamp is
>   effectively infinite, as 64 bits can represent approximately 293
>   billion years in either direction.

You can also refer to some  of the other solutions:

- [What can I do as a developer?](http://2038bug.com/index.php/articles/39-developer/61-what-can-i-do-as-a-developer)
- [Wikipedia solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem#Solutions)

or you may try to use the Datetime like this:

```
$date = new DateTime('@'.$obj->date);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i: sP') ."";
```

Comment: So your solution would be to switch to a 64bit platform! :) Also maybe you can solve it by using the PHP DateTime class?

Comment: @DennisSchepers:- Added few more solutions to the answer including DateTime ;)

Comment: Thank you. I have guessed that.